# Delete vertical lines (or vertical rules) in plt.table? Let only horizontal lines as a Table not as a chart

Tags: python-2.7, graph, matplotlib, latex, seaborn

Is there any way to remove the vertical lines in a matplotlib table?
Or even using `text.usetex=True` obtain a plot (using Arial for all texts and numbers) and append a table without vertical lines?

My code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("ticks")
plt.rcParams.update({'xtick.labelsize' : 9,
                    'ytick.labelsize' : 9,
                    'mathtext.fontset' : 'stixsans',
                    'mathtext.default': 'regular'
                    })

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.17, right=0.96, top=0.97, bottom=0.09)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5, 3.4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Unit ('+u'μ'+r'velocity $\cdot$ m$^{-2}$ s$^{-1}$)',
             size=10)

l1 = ["","t0", "t1", "t2", "t3 ", "t4", "t5", "t6"]
l2 = ["DLI", 35, 38, 10, 22, 25, 85, 22]
t = ax.table(
            colWidths=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
            cellText = [l1, l2],
            loc="upper center",
            colLoc="center",
            rowLoc="center",
            )
plt.savefig('mpl_table.png')
plt.show()
```

I tried to include some LaTeX stuff in another plot, which preserves Arial font, but does not render the table with horizontal lines [Table correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTREE.jpg). When I get the table as I want, the fonts can not be setted to Arial.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/arnaldorusso/e542b04245560300d4f7) the codes show the plots in two steps. First generating the [first plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4AU5.jpg) and after running in a new session the [second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTREE.jpg).

My main problem is to maintain the Arial font (mandatory rules in the guide for authors) and tables should be without vertical rules, as stated on [first plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4AU5.jpg).

I have here three approachs and no one satisfy those recquirements (e.g. Arial font and table with no vertical lines)

Any clues?

Cheers,
Arnaldo.